# How to extract unique values from two columns Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to get the unique values between Column (A) and Column (C) to be shown in Column (E)

Comment: Do you want values that appear in column **A** or column **C**, but not both??

Comment: i need to compare the values between Column(A) and Column(C) and show the unique  at Column (E).

Comment: Do a vlookup both ways.... takes 2 min.

Comment: thanks findwindow but i need to mak it over VBA Code

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
Sub GetUniques()
    Dim Na As Long, Nc As Long, Ne As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Na = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Nc = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Ne = 1

    For i = 1 To Na
        Cells(Ne, "E").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
        Ne = Ne + 1
    Next i
    For i = 1 To Na
        Cells(Ne, "E").Value = Cells(i, "C").Value
        Ne = Ne + 1
    Next i

    Range("E:E").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

will produce this type of result:

[image]

Comment: Dears it's wonderful but i need it like below . 

Column(A) Mike Joe Ralph 
Column(c) Mike joe 
Column(E) Ralph